# What does the following get(1) function do?

Tags: android

```
uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
```

Basically the `get(1)` part

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That will return you the path segment with index '1'.

By that, I mean, If you have `content://com.myapp/first/second/third/`
It will return 'second'.
get(2) will return 'third' 
and so on...

Comment: Will it Divide the whole String by looking the '/'?

Comment: I would assume it would ignore the '://', but yes, I think so.

Comment: Also, it will skip an empty path like '/first//third/'

Comment: Hence it will return only path so in above example get(2) should return third (entire path is first/second/third, i think so)

Comment: @SayemSiam Correct, sorry I didn't clarify

Answer (score 2):

In my tests, calling getPathSegments on the Uri below:

```
content://example.cs454.sunshine/weather/90015/1463468400000
```

yielded a List with these contents:

```
index 0 weather
index 1 90015
index 2 1463468400000
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us what uri's type is but if it is a `Uri` object then looking at the [Android URI Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getPathSegments%28%29) we can see that `getPathSegments` returns a List of Strings.  Then calling `get(1)` returns the 2nd item in the list returned by `getPathSegments()`.

The code could be re-written as follows:

```
List<String> segments = ui.getPathSegments();
String secondItem = segments.get(1);
```

Comment: Will it Divide the whole String by looking the '/'?